# Is it true that the sum of all numbers equal 0?

Tags: arithmetic, infinity

I'm not a mathematician but I'm studying Nothing, so 0 is relevant, and I'm wondering about the fact that numbers seem to be mutually canceling polarities extending from 0, that is `0 = n - n` or `0 = (+n) + (-n)` and:

`...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2...`
`...-2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2...`

So at the very least if you equally extend two collection of numbers from 0 in both directions and sum them it will always equal 0, but I'm not sure what would happen if you have two sets with **all** the numbers in both directions, as well as an infinite fractional resolution between whole numbers, because then both the sets would be infinite, or negative and positive infinities `0 = (+Infinite) + (-Infinite)`, that is if that makes sense (not sure how you would define e.x. infinite positive whole numbers).

Also I seem to remember that there is something called "complex numbers" which aren't present on the number line.

So:

1. Summing a finite set of polarizing whole numbers extending from 0 with a finite resolution between whole numbers will always equal 0.
2. Is this also true if we include more numbers then the ones on the number line (complex numbers, etc)?
3. Is this also true for an infinite number of whole numbers with an infinite fractional resolution?
4. Is `"The sum of all numbers equals 0"` True?
5. Is there any formal way to define `#1` and `#4`?

### Clarification

The calculation I'm interested in also has these arbitrary restrictions:

- "all numbers" means all numbers with only one instance of each number within the formula
- the order of the numbers in the calculation is 0+(+1)+(-1)+(+2)+(-2)... etc.

Comment: You could also add « 1 » to all numbers. It doesn't change what you are summing (you still have all numbers), but then, by your line of argument, you get 1 as a result. Thus 0=1. There must be something wrong...

Comment: Something to think about: you try to add all the integers up, so you start with $0+1+(-1)+2+(-2)+\cdots$, and at the odd steps you get a sum of $0$. So you say the sum must be zero (never mind the fact that at the even steps you have positive sums that get ever larger...). But I sum them a different way: $0+1+2+(-1)+3+(-2)+4+(-3)+\cdots$, ... and at every step I have a positive sum. So I conclude the sum cannot possibly be zero. The problem is that the sum of all numbers is not well-defined as an ordinary series like you'd handle in calculus.

Comment: Hence, when you want to define a sum, you also need to define what order you are summing terms in. Rearranging the terms of a conditionally convergent series can change the limit.

Comment: @Olivier clarification: I meant a single instance of all numbers, you can't use 1 two times, wondering what would happen under that restriction.

Comment: @Element118 the order is positive number (+n) plus negative number (-n), where in each step n is the next number on the number line, so 0+(+1)+(-1)+(+2)+(-2)...

Comment: $0+t-t^2+2t^3-2t^4+\dots=t(1-t)(1+2t^2+3t^4+4t^6+\dots)$, setting $t$ to $1$ gives a value of $0$. (If I understand how this works correctly...)

Comment: @01AutoMonkey, he wasn't saying that you use $1$ twice.  He's saying that if you take the set of all numbers, and then replace each number $x$ by $x+1$, then the result is still the set of all numbers.

Comment: Essentially you are right, if you are looking at the integration from -infinity to +infinity. You can create various strange results since you deal with infinite number of members in sets. As demonstrated by the series that jumps between 0 and infinity...

Comment: @Element, your description of the series on the right is not exactly the one on the left.

Comment: My point is that you can rearrange (translation is a rearrangement in this case) the series so that it's limit is whatever number you want. Therefore it makes no sense to talk about « the sum of all numbers », since it is not well-defined. See @D_S comment. (You did sum all natural numbers, in a very specific way, so that the result is 0. I can do the same, by summing them differently, to get 1 as a result, or any other number I want.)

Comment: So now your edit has literally begged the question, by stipulating that only rearrangements that *don't make the value of the sum nonzero* are allowed!

Comment: There is a *very important* difference between saying « all numbers sum to 0 » versus « this particular way of summing numbers gives 0 ». I downvoted your answer since you modified it to disregard the correct answers to the incorrect conjecture.

Comment: @pjs36 yes, I guess what I'm really after is "can the sum of all numbers equal 0 and in what cases" rather then "does the sum of all numbers equal 0 all the time (no matter order, etc)". But yeah, maybe I shouldn't evolve my question after replies?

Comment: @Oliver see my last comment, what I realize I'm after now is "can the sum of all numbers equal 0 and in what cases" rather then "does the sum of all numbers equal 0 all the time (no matter order, etc)", I see that it might be a bad idea to change my question in this way midway, maybe I should edit it back and ask this question again in say 2 months when it's gotten more clear to me?

Comment: Yes, I think you should stick to your original question for now. Some questions to think about: what does it mean to sum an infinite number of things? How can such a sum be defined and does that definition makes sense? Does it matter in which order the things are summed? etc.

Comment: @Olivier done. thanks for all the input, got allot I can work with until next time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1-2. Yes, as long as if some number $a$ is summed $-a$ is also summed the same number of times, the finite sum will always be $0$. This is true for complex numbers as well. Since the sum is finite, this is already defined formally.

3-5. The sum of an infinite set of numbers is only well defined when the sum eventually approaches a finite number. For example, $1 + \frac{1}2 + \frac{1}4 + \frac{1}8 + ...$ gets arbitrarily close to 2, so the sum may be defined rigorously to be exactly 2. Such a series is called "convergent." The sum you want to evaluate, $$1 -1 + 2 - 2 + 3 - 3 + ...$$ does not approach a value, so it is not a well-defined sum in the usual sense (this type of series is called "divergent"). However, there are ways to define such a sum. For example, if $s_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series, the limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{s_0 + s_1 + s_2 + ... + s_n}{n + 1}$$ 
is known as the *Cesáro sum* of the series when the limit exists. For your series, this limit still does not exist, so in the Cesáro sense your sum is also divergent. Another method of calculating a divergent sum is to define a function $$ 
f(s) = \frac{1}{{a_0}^s} + \frac{1}{{a_1}^s} + \frac{1}{{a_2}^s} + ...
$$

where the $a_i$ are the $i$th terms of the series one wishes to sum. Complex valued functions such as $f(s)$ may be unambiguously continued to numbers even where a defining sum such as the one for $f(s)$ above does not converge (this is known as the "analytic continuation" of a function). The *zeta regularization* of a sum  is the value of the analytic continuation at $-1$. For your series, the sum $$
1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} - \frac{1}{2^s} + ...
$$
is $0$ whenever it converges and thus the analytic continuation evaluated at $-1$ is $0$, so in the sense of zeta regularization your sum is indeed zero. While for this series, the sum is what is "should" be intuitively, this is not always the case. For example, $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ...$ is $\frac{1}2$ in Césaro summation and does not exist in zeta regularization. If you are interested in reading more about summing divergent series, [this](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries) is a good book.

Comment: Hello, your link to the book has broken. Do you remember what book you referenced?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** You're asking a tough question. It's tough because it really requires some detailed thinking, and perhaps highlights how "common sense" can lead us astray, when thinking about the infinite. What follows is some expository noodling, and then a disappointing answer.

---

The standard, rigorous approach is the one you'll find in any calculus text; [Stewart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538497815) or [Rogawski](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142923184X) for example.

To talk about an infinite series $a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$, we define the $N$th partial sum $S_N = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n$ as the sum of the first $N$ terms. The $a_n$ are the things we're adding up, and they're inherently ordered. For you, $a_0 = 0,\ a_1 = 1,\ a_2 = (-1)$, and so on.

Then, to answer the question, "Does $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ converge (that is to say, have a nice finite value)?" we have to decide whether the sequence of partial sums $S_N$ converges to a nice finite value. To do this, we'd need to know how to define convergence of a sequence, which isn't too bad, although it is fairly technical.

But the point is, it takes work, and lots of careful reasoning!

Mathematicians have been working with the infinite and the infinitesimal for an extremely long time (thousands of years, in fact) but it was only relatively recently, in the mid-to-late nineteenth century, that we'd worked out all of the philosophical and logical bugs, so to speak, by converting the old reasoning to something considered more rigorous by modern standards. In the 18th century, the great [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) may very well have said your series converged (but that's a complete guess, for illustrative purposes only!)

Do note that there are various provisos to everything I'm saying; it's not  quite as cut-and-dried as I've presented (see the answer that refers to divergent series, something I know literally nothing about). Mathematics is quite a diverse field populated with many varying opinions and opinionated people :)

For interesting historical bits, see [this page](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/The_rise_of_calculus.html) for an overview, or George Berkeley's criticism of Newton's calculus, snippets available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst). People like George Berkeley are *why* mathematicians needed to do a logical cleanup on early calculus in the nineteenth century.

---

**Stab at actual answer**

The issue here is that, while half the time we do indeed get $0$ after adding up finitely many terms, the other half of the time -- if we add one more term -- we get very very far away from $0$ (as far away as you'd like; when you add $-1000$ for example, the partial sum is $-1000$). Since this happens, then using the standard definition of the various limits involved, we'd have to say the sum does not converge, even with its typical order.

In order to make it convergent, you basically have to stipulate that you're really adding both $n$ and $-n$ at the same step, so your series is as boring as $0 + 0 + 0 + \ldots = 0$.